# Check if Screen is Touched

Tags: events, button, touch, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1, how can I trigger a method every time the screen (with the exception of the `Command Bar` or other `Button`s) is touched?

I could use a massive `Button`, but that just seems...terrible.

I will have some `TextBlock`s on the screen, and I still want the method to trigger even if they are the things being touched.

So basically, I am looking for a method that will fire if anything that is not a `Button` is touched.

I have been looking at the massive Windows Phone API, but it is challenging, as I am not really sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of *PointerEntered* event of [CoreWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow):

```cs
// in MainPage constructor for example:
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerEntered += CoreWindow_PointerEntered;

private void CoreWindow_PointerEntered(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
{
    // do your code here
    Debug.WriteLine("Screen touched");
}
```

Note also that you have couple of more nice events to play with.

Comment: Thank you, but that overrides the button pressed. was hoping for more of a backgroundy sort of thing

Comment: It should fire every time the screen is touchen, no matter if it's button, textblock and so on. If you want a selective eventhandler, maybe you can check the position of pointpressed and check if it's in Button's bounds. What if the user click not a button, nor textblock, but some empty space?